# No se aplica un custom color con CSS a Footer de Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Estoy usando **Bootstrap 5.2** en un proyecto que tiene un Navbar y un Footer, estoy aplicandole los colores de Spotify y logré cambiar el navbar correctamente en CSS con este color: `(#191414)`
[image: nabvar]

El problema es que en el footer, no se aplica ese mismo color! *Se le agrega una especie de filtro sepia.* No logro encontrar el problema:/ adjunto el código del footer:
[image: footer]

```
<style>
      #kolam {
        background-color: #191414;
      }
    </style>
    <footer class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center py-3 px-3 border-success border-2 border-top" id="kolam">
      <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center">
        <a href="/" class="mb-3 me-2 mb-md-0 text-decoration-none lh-1" style="color: #1DB954;">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-spotify fa-xl"></i>
        </a>
        <span class="mb-3 mb-md-0 text-light">© 2022 SpotiFri</span>
      </div>
  
      <ul class="nav col-md-4 justify-content-end list-unstyled d-flex">
        <li class="ms-3"><a style="color: #1DB954;" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-bounce fa-xl"></i></a></li>
        <li class="ms-3"><a style="color: #1DB954;" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-bounce fa-xl"></i></a></li>
        <li class="ms-3"><a style="color: #1DB954;" href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-github fa-bounce fa-xl"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-success border-top pb-3 mt-3">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2" style="color: #1DB954;">Desarrollador</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2" style="color: #1DB954;">Código Fuente</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2" style="color: #1DB954;">Lista de APK's</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2" style="color: #1DB954;">Otras herramientas</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p class="text-center text-light fw-bold">Este sitio web es gratuito, sin anuncios, libre de virus y de código abierto en <a href="#" class="link-primary">Github.</a></p>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: No se a que te refieres... yo lo veo negro azabache todo!   Aún así, has probado poniendole un !important a ese color?

Comment: @masterguru no:( son colores diferentes, el del footer es un negro más claro y la navbar es mucho más intensa

Comment: Usando el plugin colorzilla de firefox me dice que ambos son #191414... no será que tienes la pantalla sucia?  Ya verás, usa algun tipo de photoshop que tengas a mano y con el selector de color verás que te dicen el mismo

Comment: El que sí cambia es el color verde, pero el negro es el mismo

Comment: Ya veo, nunca me había pasado algo así pero voy a revisarlo. Muchas gracias amigo!

Comment: Ya te digo, que no sea que al ser verdes distintos te confunda... usa selectores de color para compararlos mejor y no te fies tanto de la pantalla, que a veces son los pixeles que ya los tienes quemados (o las gafas sucias, o la vista cansada, je)